# Converting date inside loop breaks loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

So I have a MySQL query feeding into an array to sanitize it to meet the needs of a graphing library. I tried to convert the hours, currently in 24h format, to a slightly prettier 12h format. But when I do, it kills the loop after one iteration, and so only one value gets fed to the graph (instead of values for the whole day). I'm very new to PHP, so I'm not sure what is breaking this. What is the proper way to accomplish what I need to do?

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT HOUR( TIMESTAMP ) AS HOUR , COUNT( DISTINCT detected_key ) AS num_rows
            FROM Visitors
            WHERE TIMESTAMP >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
            GROUP BY HOUR( TIMESTAMP ) 
            ORDER BY  `id` ASC 
            LIMIT 0 , 24');

while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $prettytime  = DATE("g:i a", STRTOTIME($row['HOUR']));
    $visit[$prettytime]= $row['num_rows'];  
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried using DATE_FORMAT already, but that still just outputs as the 24h format. The only documentation I found on the MySQL website always had it right after SELECT.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( TIMESTAMP,  "%l:%i %a" ) , HOUR( TIMESTAMP ) AS HOUR , COUNT( DISTINCT detected_key ) AS num_rows
FROM Visitors
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY HOUR( TIMESTAMP ) 
ORDER BY  `id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 24
```

Here is [the website](http://dark-forest.net/darktrak/) where you can see the graph. The one using the query above is the top left graph.

Comment: why not just convert the date in the query instead of pulling it as an hour and then converting it there then all you have to do is $visit[$pretty_time_from_db] instead of fannying around.  also DATE and STRTOTIME are php functions should be lower case.

Comment: [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) ?

Comment: What is exact error that you're getting?

Comment: I updated the question. I had already tried that and it didn't work, and I couldn't find any examples of using DATE_FORMAT differently, so I am assuming there is something broken with the rest of my query. It still outputs in 24h format.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to work rather nicely from a database field defined as

```
`thetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then using the MySQL DATE_FORMAT() and HOUR() functions :-

```
SELECT thetime, DATE_FORMAT(thetime, '%r') from test_table
```

Gives the results :-

```
2014-01-20 10:57:45, 10:57:45 AM
2014-01-20 23:59:31, 11:59:31 PM
```

Or

```
SELECT thetime, HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(thetime, '%r')) from test_table
```

Gives :-

```
2014-01-20 10:57:45, 10
2014-01-20 23:59:31, 11
```

Comment: I modified the table and query like you suggested, but it still outputs to 24h.

Comment: How was your `TIMESTAMP` field originally defined then?

Comment: It was originally a DATETIME field, but I emptied the database and altered the field according to your specifications.

Comment: Are you trying to collect data to plot on the `unique visits last 24 hrs` graph. If so surely you need an array indexed on `'0 to 23'` i.e. the 24hr time.

Comment: It already is, I'm pretty sure. At least, it shows up on the graph as 24h format, I just can't get it to convert to a pretty 12h format.